# dynamic iterative programming to generate combinations

Tags: c++, dynamic, vector, combinations

*Updated with my own version of the program :*

I'm trying to do an iterative dynamic programming to generate `n choose k` combination.

Say I've 4 vectors of values

```
v1 : 1 1 1
v2 : 2 2 2
v3 : 3 3 3
v4 : 4 4 4
```

Now I use addition as my aggregate function and I want to generate `4 choose 2` combinations of vectors as follows :

```
v1v2 : 3 3 3
v1v3 : 4 4 4
v1v4 : 5 5 5
v2v3 : 5 5 5
v2v4 : 6 6 6
v3v4 : 7 7 7
```

A naive way to do this would be to go through every pair and find the result. if the `N` and `k` are very large this is very very inefficient. So an alternative way to this would be recursive/iterative dynamic programming. Recursion for very large N and k would take up a lot of memory so the ideal way to this would be iterative dynamic programming which can be done as follows :

Consider the following table row header is `N` and the column header is `k` and our objective is to find `N choose k` : 
[image: Table1]

We can find `N choose k` combination using dynamic program by following way :

[image: Table2]

The approach is as follows :

1. Block[0,1] and Block[0,2] always returns [ ]. {[ ] denotes an empty value as there are no values there}.
2. Block[1,1] receives [ ], computes {v1} + [ ] (which is v1 itself) , saves it to Block [1,1].
3. Block[1,2] receives [ ], does {v1} + [ ] & {v2} + [ ], saves it to Block [1,2].
4. Block[1,3] receives [ ], does {v1} + [ ], {v2} + [ ] + {v3} U [ ], Block [1,3].
5. Block[2,4] receives :

   - [{v1}] from [1,1] and computes {v1} + {v2},
   - [{v1}{v2}] from [1,2] and computes {v1} + {v3} and {v2} + {v3}
   - [{v1}, {v2}, {v3}] from [1,3] and computes {v4} + {v1}, {v4} + {v2} and {v4} + {v3}, saves it to  Block [2,4].

Now we have all the values we need in Block [2,4]. how can i code this concept efficiently in C++ ?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my idea :

I don't know if this is right. Sorry

=========================================================

```
//Block [0...k][0...n]; 
//Block[i][j] contains i-set groups (for eg :if i = 2 it will have v1v2, v1v3, etc..)

//initially, Block[0][i] = [ ] for 0 <= i <= n and all other Block [i][j] = [ $ ]
// "$" is just a symbol to indicate that no computation is done on that block

algorithm(int k, int n) //k-point skyline groups from n number of points.
{
   if( Block[k][n] != [ $ ] ) return memory[k][n];

   Group = [ ]; //G indicate a collection of vectors
   for( int i = k; i <= n; i++ )
   {
      Group` = algorithm(k-1, i-1);
      for( each v` in Group` )
      {
         Group = Group + (group` + v_i);
      }
   }
memory[k][n] = Group;
return Group;
}
```

=========================================================

Here is my program for the above mentioned algorithm :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#define DIMENSIONS 5 // No. of elements in the vector. eg. v1: 1 1 1 1 1 
using namespace std;

typedef std::set < int > my_set;  // To hold vector id's
typedef std::vector < int > my_vector; // To hold values of the vector's
typedef std::vector < std::pair < my_set, my_vector > > my_vector_pair;
typedef std::map < my_set, my_vector > my_map;
typedef std::vector < vector < std::pair < int,my_map > > > my_pair;
typedef my_map::iterator m_it;

my_vector_pair bases;  // To hold all the initial <id,vector_values> pair
my_map data, G;
my_pair memory;

void print(my_map& data)
{
    for( m_it it(data.begin()) ; it!=data.end(); ++it) 
    {   
        cout << "Id : ";
        copy(it->first.begin(), it->first.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
        cout << " => value : ";
        copy (it->second.begin(),it->second.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------\n";
}

my_map union_(my_map& G, int p) 
{
    static my_map result;
    my_set id;
    my_vector scores;
    result.clear();
    for (m_it it(G.begin()); it != G.end(); ++it) 
    {
        id = it->first;
        scores = it->second;
        id.insert( bases.at(p-1).first.begin(),bases.at(p-1).first.end() );

            for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSIONS; j++) 
            {
                scores.at(j) += bases.at(p - 1).second.at(j);
            }
            result.insert(make_pair(id, scores));
    }
    return result;
}

my_map algorithm_(int k, int n) {

    unsigned long size = memory.at(n).size();
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (memory.at(n).at(i).first == k) {
            return memory.at(n).at(i).second; //if exists in hash table then no need to calculate again
        }
    }
    my_map G_k_1;

    if (k != n)
    {
        G_k_1 = algorithm_(k, n - 1);
        if(G_k_1.size() == 0)
            {
                return G_k_1;
            }
    }
    G_k_1 = algorithm_(k - 1, n - 1);
    if(G_k_1.size() == 0)
    {
        return G_k_1;
    }

    G_k_1 = union_(G_k_1, n);

    if (k != n) {
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < memory.at(n - 1).size(); i++) {
            if (memory.at(n - 1).at(i).first == k) {
                G_k_1.insert(memory.at(n - 1).at(i).second.begin(), memory.at(n - 1).at(i).second.end());
                memory.at(n - 1).at(i).second.clear();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    std::pair<int,my_map> temp;
    temp.first = k ;
    temp.second = G_k_1;
    memory.at(n).push_back( temp ); //storing in hash table for further use
    return memory.at(n).back().second;
}


int main()
{
   my_vector v1,v2,v3,v4,v5;
   my_set s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;
   for(int i = 1; i<=5; ++i)
   {
      v1.push_back(1);
      v2.push_back(2);
      v3.push_back(3);
      v4.push_back(4);
      v5.push_back(5);
   }


   s1.insert(1);
   s2.insert(2);
   s3.insert(3);
   s4.insert(4);
   s5.insert(5);

   bases.insert(bases.end(),make_pair(s1,v1));
   bases.insert(bases.end(),make_pair(s2,v2));
   bases.insert(bases.end(),make_pair(s3,v3));
   bases.insert(bases.end(),make_pair(s4,v4));
   bases.insert(bases.end(),make_pair(s5,v5));

   my_set empty_set;
   my_vector empty_group(DIMENSIONS);
   G.insert(make_pair(empty_set,empty_group));

   vector<std::pair<int,my_map> > empty_element;
   empty_element.push_back(make_pair(0,G));
   for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {  // 5 is the total number od vectors : v1,v2,v3,v4,v5
       memory.push_back(empty_element);
   }



   data.insert(bases.begin(),bases.end());
   cout << endl << "The intial set of vectors are : " << endl;
   print ( data );

   int k;
   cout << "N = 5 " << endl << "Enter the value of k : ";
   cin >> k;

   cout << "The values for N choose k are : " << endl;
   data = algorithm_(k,5); 

   print ( data ); 

}
```

If you run the program you know what I wanted to achieve and in what way. This ALGORITHM (not program) might not be efficient for a smaller number of vectors but it will be when N > 50k and k ~ 10. I'm aware the implementation of the algorithm (my program) is very inefficient. Is there any way to improve it ? I think the same algorithm can be implemented in a much more elegant fashion. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What size of k and n will you be going up to? If it's not a huge number then you could probably use a LUT to determine your value.

Comment: @Shaktal : I'm going for N > 50k and k ~ 10. I'm using powerful servers so this is not that big.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies for misunderstanding your answer previously, I didn't really understand what you were trying to do in your post, I thought you were just looking for a non-recursive way of computing nCk :P

I've created a class, `CombinationGenerator` to produce the combinations of vectors, which I believe is what you want. It works by producing a vector of ints representing the indices of the elements to aggregate (I've included a `main` function below which should help to explain it programmatically).

Here is the header file: http://pastebin.com/F5x4WKD9

And the source file: http://pastebin.com/CTV1PLRb

And here is a sample main function:

```
typedef std::vector<int> vecInt;

int main() {

    // We have a deque containing 3 elements (try using experimenting with data
    // types to test space complexity, std::set or std::unordered_set might be an option)
    vecInt vec1;
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        vec1.push_back(1);
    }
    vecInt vec2;
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        vec2.push_back(2);
    }
    vecInt vec3;
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        vec3.push_back(3);
    }
    vecInt vec4;
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        vec4.push_back(4);
    }
    vecInt vec5;
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        vec5.push_back(5);
    }

    std::deque<std::vector<int>> dequeVecs;
    dequeVecs.push_back( vec1 );
    dequeVecs.push_back( vec2 );
    dequeVecs.push_back( vec3 );
    dequeVecs.push_back( vec4 );
    dequeVecs.push_back( vec5 );

    // Create our CombinationGenerator:
    CombinationGenerator* gen = new CombinationGenerator();

    g_pCombinationGen = gen;

    gen = NULL;

    unsigned long long size = g_pCombinationGen->ComputeBinomialCoefficient( dequeVecs.size(), 2 );

    std::vector<int> currCombination;

    g_pCombinationGen->Initialize( dequeVecs.size(), 2, size );

    while( !g_pCombinationGen->IsFinished() )
    {
        currCombination = g_pCombinationGen->NextCombination();

        std::vector<int> result;
        for( int i = 0; i < dequeVecs[0].size(); i++ )
        {
            result.push_back( dequeVecs[currCombination[0]][i] + dequeVecs[currCombination[1]][i] );
        }

        std::cout << "(";
        for( int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++ )
        {
            std::cout << result[i];
        }
        std::cout << ")" << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Whilst this may look rather large, if you analyze the space usage of it (let's assume that you're using n = 50,000 and k = 1000:

There are 50,000 vectors each containing 3 ints (let's assume a reasonably harsh overhead per vector of 32bytes, it's normally around 20 on most implementations): So, `(50,000 * 3 * 4) + (50,000 * 32) = 2,200,000 Bytes`

You're then containing this in a deque, which we will also assume has an overhead of 32bytes: `2,200,000 + 32 = 2,200,032 Bytes`

We're also having an instance running of the Combination Generator, this has 5 member variables, two ints, two long longs, and a vector containing k ints (in this case 1000), so: `2,200,032 + (2*4) + (2*8) + (1000*4) + 32 = 2,204,056 Bytes`

We also have the vector containing the result for each iteration again with k ints: `2,204,056 + (1000*4) + 32 = 2,208,088 Bytes`

As you can see, this is far below your 4GB of memory. NOTE: It would not be possible to store each of these vectors in memory regardless of what implementation you used, as there would be over `9.94 x 10^2126` vectors containing results. Even if you chose a small value of k such as 10, you would still have over `2.69 x 10^40`.

I hope this time I've understood what it is you're asking for! If not, I'll try and understand again what it is you're trying to achieve. :)

Comment: I fail to understand your program. Could you elaborate on it please ? Thanks.

Comment: It computes nCk using the [multiplicative identity](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/8/1/a/81a14681d033e51e4b731b7f2679e8ba.png). I've updated my post to make it clearer what is going on. :)

Comment: I'm not sure but wouldn't this take up a lot of memory space ? For very large values (considering each value is a vector of values) this would take up the entire memory, isn't it ? My processing power could be distributed but my memory is very limited ~ 4GB.

Comment: No, because it's only dealing with 3 variables within the for loop (which only takes up a few instructions in assembly). Thus those variables would only take up a small amount of memory (8B for the long long, 12B for the 3 ints). It also wouldn't take particularly long to compute, especially with a fast processor (I just computed 5000C30000 in less than a second).

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. My input is actually a vector of values and my aggregate function is addition. So if it is 5C2 I want to list out all the 10 possible combinations of it. i.e. the output should be something like this : 
v1v2 = 3 3 3 ;
v1v3 = 4 4 4 ;
.
.
.
v4v5 = 9 9 9. So imagine I had 50K vectors like this. Storing it, computing its values and listing all out is a big process. If I wanted only the value it is pretty easy. I wouldn't even care about the method.

Comment: My apologies if I'm not catching your point but I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand what you want now, you will input a set of n-vectors, and you want to aggregate all of the possible combinations of these through addition? So all possible additions of vectors have taken place?

Comment: Yes that's right. I don't get the second part of your question though.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please give me some time to understand what is really going on in the header files and the program and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I updated the question and added my own program. please have a look. Thank you.