# How can I find all possible letter combinations of a string?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I am given a string and i need to find all possible letter combinations of this string. What is the best way I can achieve this?
example:

```
abc
```

result:

```
abc
acb
bca
bac
cab
cba
```

i have nothing so far. i am not asking for code. i am just asking for the best way to do it? an algorithm? a pseudocode? maybe a discussion?

Comment: std::next_permuatation should do the trick if you using c++

Comment: Strictly speaking, those are *permutations* and there are `n!` of them: `n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can sort it then use std::next_permutation

take a look at the example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/

Answer (score 1):

Do you want combinations or permutations? For example, if your string is "abbc" do you want to see "bbac" once or twice?

If you actually want permutations you can use `std::next_permutation` and it'll take care of all the work for you.

Comment: i want to see bbac once...  so what is my problem called?

Comment: You want the combinations, rather than the permutations of the string. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the combinations (order independant) You can use a combination finding algorithm such as that found either [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849233/dynamic-iterative-programming-to-generate-combinations/6850169#6850169) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211915/combination-and-permutation-in-c). Alternatively, you can use [this](http://www.merriampark.com/comb.htm) (a java implementation of a combination generator, with an example demonstrating what you want.

Alternatively, if you want what you have listed in your post (the permutations), then you can (for C++) use `std::next_permutation` found in `<algorithm.h>`. You can find more information on `std::next_permutation` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/).

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `std::next_permutation`:

```
std::string s = "abc";
do
{
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
} while (std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied from an old Wikipedia article;

For every number k, with 0 ≤ k < n!, the following algorithm generates a unique permutation on sequence s.

```
function permutation(k, s) {
     for j = 2 to length(s) {
        swap s[(k mod j) + 1] with s[j]; // note that our array is indexed starting at 1
        k := k / j;        // integer division cuts off the remainder
     }
     return s;
}
```